# Позиционирование двух блоков и текста

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день, столкнулся с ситуацией где нужно сделать так что бы два блока были с background и наезжали друг на друга но что бы текст был выше них, не могу разобраться как это сделать.

```
<div class="firstBlock">
     <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="secondBlock">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть так ?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/bqWQyG?editors=1100)

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html,body{
height:100%;
}

.wrapper{
width:100%;
height:50%;
position:relative;
}

.block1,.block2{
width:50%;
height:100%;
float:left;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.block1{
background:blue;
}

.block2{
background:red;
}

p{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <p>Это текст выше этих блоков</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

например:

```css
.firstBlock {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.firstBlock p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  color:#fff;
}

.secondBlock {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstBlock">
     <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="secondBlock">
</div>
```